# How to define (f)lex/bison pattern ( /* comment*/ ) and/or ( 100 /* comment*/ )

Tags: yacc, lex

how can I define the lex pattern ( ), or ( /* rem */ ),  and ( /* foo */ 100 /* foo */ )
in using gnu (f)lex tool.

```
_space [ \t]
id     [a-zA-Z_]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]
digit  [0-9]

math_ops   [\+\-\/\*\^\%]
rem_expr   (({_space}*)*|("/*".*"*/")*|("//".*)*|([\n]*))*
arr_digid  ("("*({digit}*|{id}*)*")"*){arr_expr1}*{math_ops}+
arr_expr1  {rem_expr}*{digit}*{rem_expr}*
arr_expr2  {rem_expr}*

%%

\({arr_expr2}*\)  {
    return _REM_;
}

\({arr_expr1}*\)  {
    return _PATTERN2_;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you do not return comments or whitespace from a lexer. Why would you? They are, by definition, not part of the semantics of the program you are trying to parse.

On the whole, the easiest way to deal with them is to just ignore them. Below, the first pattern matches any whitespace character other than newline (Use `[[:space:]]` to also ignore newlines), and the second one is a way of matching C-style comments. (`"/*".*"*/"` doesn't work because it will match from the beginning of the first comment on a line to the end of the last one.)

```
[[:blank:]]  ;
[/][*][^*]*[*]+([^/*][^*]*[*]+)[/]  ;
```

The fact that the patterns do not have an action (or, in general, do not have a `return` statement in their action) means that the (f)lex-generated scanner will simply proceed to analyze the next token.

Some other notes:

1. It's really not necessary to define a shortcut for every pattern. There is no problem with putting a pattern directly in the lex actions. And you certainly don't need to define shortcuts for character classes which already have shortcuts (like `[[:blank:]]` and `[[:digit:]]`.
2. You don't need to backslash escape characters inside a character class, although with a couple of characters order is important. (That's why I used `[*]` in the C-comment pattern; I could equally have used `"*"` or `\*`, but I personally prefer `[*]`.) So you could have defined:

   ```
   math_ops   [+/*^%-]
   ```

   The <kbd>-</kbd> must go either at the end or the beginning of the list; <kbd>^</kbd> cannot go at the beginning, and (though you don't use it) <kbd>]</kbd> would have to go at the beginning. The only character which requires backslash-escaping is a backslash itself.
3. However, my preference is always to let single-character tokens be handled with a single default rule at the end:

   ```
   .    { return yytext[0]; }
   ```

   This is much more maintainable, and avoids the need to invent arbitrary token names for single-character tokens. You can just use a single-quoted character in your bison/yacc file.